# Finding the 3 top selling products in each category

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, sum, window-functions

I am trying to find the 3 top selling products in each category. But the SQL I tried does not yield the correct results. Here's the things I did:

**Products Table:**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Products](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [name] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [category] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Products] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)
```

| id | name | category |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | prod1 | cat1 |
| 2 | prod2 | cat1 |
| 3 | prod3 | cat1 |
| 4 | prod4 | cat1 |
| 5 | prod5 | cat1 |
| 6 | prod6 | cat2 |
| 7 | prod7 | cat2 |
| 8 | prod8 | cat2 |
| 10 | prod10 | cat2 |

**OrderItems table:**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[OrderItems](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [prodID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [quantity] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_OrderItems] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OrderItems]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_OrderItems_Products] FOREIGN KEY([prodID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Products] ([id])

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OrderItems] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_OrderItems_Products]
```

| id | prodID | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 10 |
| 2 | 2 | 6 |
| 3 | 2 | 6 |
| 4 | 4 | 3 |
| 5 | 3 | 2 |
| 6 | 6 | 10 |
| 7 | 7 | 1 |

**SQL I tried:**

```
select *
from (select p1.id, p1.category, (select sum(quantity) from OrderItems as oi where oi.prodID = p1.id) as sales
from Products as p1) as p2
where p2.sales >= (
    select distinct(sales)
    from (select p1.id, p1.category, (select sum(quantity) from OrderItems as oi where oi.prodID = p1.id) as sales
from Products as p1) as p3
    where p2.category = p3.category
    order by sales desc
    offset 2 rows fetch next 1 rows only)
```

**Expected Result:**

| id | category | sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | cat1 | 10 |
| 2 | cat1 | 12 |
| 4 | cat1 | 3 |
| 6 | cat2 | 10 |
| 7 | cat2 | 1 |

Actual Result:

| id | category | sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | cat1 | 10 |
| 2 | cat1 | 12 |
| 4 | cat1 | 3 |

What is the mistake in the query? And is there a better way to achieve the result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can join the tables and aggregate to get the total sales for each product.
Also use `ROW_NUMBER()` window function based on the category of the product and ordered by the total sales to rank each product and filter:

```
SELECT id, category, sales
FROM (
  SELECT p.id, 
         MAX(category) category, 
         SUM(o.quantity) sales,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MAX(category) ORDER BY SUM(o.quantity) DESC) rn
  FROM Products p INNER JOIN OrderItems o
  ON o.prodID = p.id
  GROUP BY p.id
) t
WHERE rn <= 3
ORDER BY id;
```

Or, aggregate first in `OrderItems` and then join:

```
SELECT id, category, sales
FROM (
  SELECT p.id, 
         p.category, 
         o.sales,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY p.category ORDER BY o.sales DESC) rn
  FROM Products p 
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT prodID, SUM(quantity) sales
    FROM OrderItems
    GROUP BY prodID
  ) o ON o.prodID = p.id
) t
WHERE rn <= 3
ORDER BY id;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=81b99ba27d68da6e2ca7d47028157ad9).

Comment: Thanks for the alternative solutions with row number. Also, could you spot the mistake in the solution I posted?

Comment: @JohnL. for `'cat2'` the 3d value of `sales` returned by `offset 2 rows fetch next 1 rows only` is `null` so the  condition is equivalent to `where p2.sales >= null` which fails because any comparison to `null` returns also `null`.